# Why firebase generating new document id?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem that I couldn't reach my documentID in the Phome collection.

[image: I want to put 4vv1Hd...document id]

[image: to the Users/K0S71../Housename:]

I want to put `4vv1Hd...` document id to the `Users/K0S71../Housename`:

But firebase generating new document id and put it there I guess.

My Codes:

```
let documentData["email":UserSingleton.sharedUserInfo.email,"username":UserSingleton.sharedUserInfo.username,"Housename":UserSingleton.sharedUserInfo.housename] as [String:Any]
    fireStoreDatabase.collection("Phome").document().collection("Users").addDocument(data: documentData) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            //
        }
        }

     }
    func getUserInfo(){
    fireStoreDatabase.collection("UserInfo").whereField("email", isEqualTo: 
    Auth.auth().currentUser!.email!).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
    if error != nil {
        self.makeAlert(title: "error", message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
    }else{
        if snapshot?.isEmpty == false && snapshot != nil{
            for document in snapshot!.documents{
              if let username =  document.get("username") as? String{
                UserSingleton.sharedUserInfo.email = Auth.auth().currentUser!.email!
                UserSingleton.sharedUserInfo.username = username
                UserSingleton.sharedUserInfo.housename = 
     self.fireStoreDatabase.collection("Phome").document().documentID

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And Singleton class here :

```
class UserSingleton{

static let sharedUserInfo = UserSingleton()

var email = ""
var username = ""
var housename = ""




private init(){

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `document()` without any parameter it generates a new document ID.

If you want to reach a specific document, you'll need to pass that document's ID into the call: `document("idOfDocument")`.

If you don't know the ID of the document, you will have to first determine that through a query. For this you must know something that identifies the document you're looking for. So something like:

```
fireStoreDatabase.collection("Phome").whereField("aFieldInPhome", isEqualTo: "aValueYouKnow")...
```